# Do all html disabled buttons have disabled attribute?

Tags: html

Q1:  Is "disabled" here considered as an attribute

```
<button disabled class> .....str.....
```

Q2:

do all html disabled buttons have a disabled attribute like:

```
<button disabled class> .....str.....
```

Comment: Q2: Are you asking if all buttons can have the attribute?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to learn more how buttons are defined in hmtl, take a look at this: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_disabled.asp

In html, the "disabled" attribute is considered as an attribute and if an button is disabled, then this attribute is set.

Here is an example of how a button can be configed in python
html.Button('Create Missing Relation Script', id='input-1', disabled=False),

Comment: MDN is a more reliable source for information than w3schools: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/disabled

Comment: thank you guys for the reply, I've looked into w3schools ones before, will checkout mdn for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Q1: Yes, it's considered a attribute.

Q2: What buttons?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question, yes, "disabled" in that context is an attribute, referring to the button of course.

To answer your second question, yes, that is how a "disabled" attribute is added to **any button**.

Example:

```html
<button type="button" disabled>You cannot click this button, it's disabled.</button>
```

I hope this answers your question. Thanks.

Comment: thank you, i always wonder if there's a html website that doesn't have disabled as attribute for their button to be disabled instead using just a different string within that class to distinguish the availiability of the button